# Is Akka a good fit for sharing single data view across separate EJBs

Tags: jakarta-ee, akka

I have a clustered JavaEE application. I would like to share a single view of a data structure between like EJBs.

I don't want the EJBs to be contending with each other to update a database and would prefer to share state in memory.

Would Akka be of use here? Transactors perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the part of just sharing a state, actors are probably not what your looking for. Akkas STM on the other hand sounds like a good fit.